# Multiple var is node app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it bad form to have multiple var calls, such as:

```
 var init = require('./config/init')(),
     config = require('./config/config'),
     express = require('express'),
     errorHandler = require('errorhandler'),
     bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
     expressValidator = require('express-validator'),
     mongoose = require('mongoose'),
     path = require('path'),
     _ = require('lodash'),
     passport = require('passport'),
     passport_config = require('./config/passport'),
     session = require('express-session'),
     MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),
     swagger = require("swagger-node-express"),
     secrets = require('./config/secrets'),
     multer = require('multer');
```

Or should I set each one by itself?

Comment: POB. I like using single `var` saves some keystrokes.

Comment: Its completely fine as long as you are comfortable.

Comment: I just started using playing with JSLint and it was freaking out - I wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Comment: This is fine. And FYI, although this is obviously a node.js example, in the case of client-side JS defining multiple variables in a single `var` statement actually is slightly more efficient since it helps with minification. But the important thing is readability; as long as it's readable it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using it to import npm modules on a global scope, it's fine. But in general, it's better practice to declare var for each variable. The reason being that missing a `,` will create any following variables in a global scope. For example, try catching the error in this:

```
var init = require('./config/init')(),
     config = require('./config/config'),
     express = require('express'),
     errorHandler = require('errorhandler'),
     bodyParser = require('body-parser')
     expressValidator = require('express-validator'),
     mongoose = require('mongoose'),
     path = require('path'),
     _ = require('lodash'),
     passport = require('passport'),
     passport_config = require('./config/passport'),
     session = require('express-session'),
     MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),
     swagger = require("swagger-node-express"),
     secrets = require('./config/secrets'),
     multer = require('multer');
```

Comment: Or you could just use strict mode...if you put "use strict" at the top of this example then you'd get a ReferenceError.

Comment: Then your entire code will have to conform to the standards of the "use strict" directive, and this doesn't just include the way you declare variables. Furthermore, browsers that don't support strict mode will run strict mode code with different behaviour from browsers that do.

Comment: @nshoute - I ran into this exact issue yesterday where I started to implement "use strict" and it caused application errors.